# Pressure on static fluid

Tags: fluid-statics

If we apply pressure on static fluid surface vertically, how could same pressure be applied by fluid in horizontal direction ?

Comment: Why not ? Why does this surprise you ?

Comment: the question is a bit vague but the pressure exerted by the fluid is given by $\rho gh$ where h is height from fluid surface so it is quite possible that sometimes when a body exerts some force vertically on the fluid surface that force **might** be equal to the force applied by that fluid in any direction

Comment: Your question has an answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/486642/why-is-horizontal-pressure-the-same-as-vertical-pressure-in-a-static-fluid?rq=1